# In Python buffer erase large output

Tags: python, comint, kill-text

Python buffers support `comint-delete-output`, but if I forget to do it before entering another command, I have a big hunk of text I can't easily erase.

In shell mode, I can set the mark and run `comint-previous-prompt`, and then erase the region. But in Python buffers, it tells me that the text is read only. I can run `read-only-mode`, to attempt to turn it off, but it doesn't work.

If I try to kill the lines manually, it mostly works (but is too tedious), but one out of every 50 lines or so will be read-only and I can't kill it.

If I try something like `M-1 0 0 C-k`, it invariably tells me the text is read-only, and won't kill any of it.

Running GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 1, aarch64-apple-darwin21.6.0, NS appkit-2113.60 Version 12.6.6 (Build 21G646)) of 2023-08-16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `comint-clear-buffer` ("C-c M-o") to remove everything. There is also `comint-kill-region` that should properly deal with the read-only prompts, at least according to its documentation.